# Is it a good idea to mention visa sponsorship in cover letter?

Tags: germany, cover-letter, visa

I have found a job notice for an internship which supports visa sponsorship for Germany. Although my background is quite matched with the needs of company, it is only an intern position, while I am an experienced engineer (1.3 year working experience).

To be honest, the biggest motivation for me, is the visa sponsorship. Is it a good idea to mention this in my cover letter?

Comment: You should research Visa rules for Germany carefully.  In some countries (notably the US), the Visa approval allows you to work in that country for that company.  If you wish to change jobs you will have to redo parts of the application with the new employer.  A visa is not a free pass to work wherever you want in that country.

Answer (score 8):

> To be honest, the biggest motivation for me, is the visa sponsorship.

I think it would be a mistake - you want to use this as an opportunity to make the case as to why you want to work for **this** company and "well, I'm in it for the Visa" isn't particularly appealing. In much the same way as going to a singles event and saying "I'd love to marry you.....for a green card!" is unlikely to work out well.

It basically infers that you don't care who you work for so long as you get the visa, and most people would prefer to hire someone who actually wants the **job**, there's likely to be no shortage of candidates who would want the job itself (regardless of whether they need a visa or not) and they are going to be no-brainer picks over you if you say that.

So try and come up with some reasons why you want the job that **aren't** the visa and use those in your cover letter instead. If you can't then I'd suggest doing both yourself and the employer a favor and moving on.

Answer (score 3):

You can mention it, but it will likely mean that you will not be considered for an interview.

Comment: the best answer here  :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not a good idea to mention anything that is a benefit to you, and not the company in any cover letter.

Cover letters should contain only reasons why they should consider you above others, and to emphasize things in your resume that match their job requirements.

In fact, we turned down a candidate who mentioned that he was very much wanting to relocate.  We couldn't take the chance that he'd use us to get here, then bail at the first opportunity.